# Pandas drop_duplicates occasionally crashes with no exception

Tags: python, pandas, windows, access-violation

I'm using `pandas` with Python 2.7 (distributed with ArcGIS Desktop 10.7, which is why I can't use Python 3), running on Windows Server 2019.

In my code I'm trying to remove duplicates from a CSV file (~100MB):

```
df = pd.read_csv(csv_file_path, dtype={
            "COLUMN_1": float,
            "COLUMN_2": int,
            "COLUMN_3": int,
            "COLUMN_4": int
        })
unique_df = df.drop_duplicates(keep="first")
unique_df.to_csv(another_csv_file_path, index=False)
```

The problem is that this code sometimes works as expected, and some other times it just crashes without any exception or warning. The process is ended and further code is not being executed.

When I run my script from Windows Task Scheduler, the Last Run Result in case of failure is `0xC0000005`. In case of success it is `0x0`.

Any suggestions?

Comment: @ScottBoston I need to use additional packages of ArcGIS in the same script, and they only work with the Python version installed with ArcGIS (which is 2.7). Shouldn't I get some kind of exception is this is a memory problem?